# Call to undefined method App\Models\Catogry::firstItem()

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a CMS project but I got this error when I create the URL & Controller for the edit button (Call to undefined method App\Models\Catogry::firstItem()).

here is the web.php page

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    // $users = User::all();
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    return view('dashboard', compact('users'));
})->name('dashboard');

//category controller
Route::get('/category/all', [CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('index.category');
Route::post('/category/add', [CategoryController::class, 'store'])->name('store.category');
Route::get('/category/edit/{id}', [CategoryController::class, 'edit']);
```

here Is the CategoryController >>

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Catogry;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Validated;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Catogry::latest()->paginate(5);
        return response()->view('Admin.category.index', compact('categories'));
    }



    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'category_name' => 'required|unique:catogries|max:25|min:4',
        ]);

        //insert with three ways *****

        // Catogry::insert([
        //     'category_name' => $request->category_name,
        //     // 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        //     'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        // ]);


        $categories = new Catogry;
        $categories->category_name = $request->category_name;
        $categories->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $categories->save();

        // $date = array();
        // $data['category_name'] = $request->category_name;
        // $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
        // DB::table('catogries')->insert($data);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Category Inserted Successfully');
    }


    public function Edit($id)
    {
        // return 'edit page';
        $categories = Catogry::findOrFail($id);
        return response()->view('Admin.category.edit', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

here is the edit.blade.php page >>

```
<form action="  " method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category_name">Edit Your Category Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_name" name="category_name" placeholder="Enter category name"
        value="{{ $categories->category_name }}">
      </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update Category</button><br>
      @error('category_name')
      <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
    @enderror
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-footer -->
  </form>
```

Comment: I checked your code, 1st you used findOrFail method that will throw an exception if the model is not found so I suggest you use the find method to get category data. I want to show your model and a brief clarification of the issue.

Comment: thanks a lot but I tried the find() method and it is still the same error 
public function Edit($id)
    {
        $categories = Catogry::find($id);
        return response()->view('Admin.category.edit', compact('categories'));
    }

Comment: I want to review your category model. Please share it.
name of the function in route and in the controller is also different. One id Edit and the other edit so also correct it as well.

Comment: thanks, I found the problem <3